# how to use gulp-rev and gulp-rev-collector to create like that: index.js--->index.js?v=098f6bcd

Tags: gulp

I modified that gulp-rev/index.js and gulp-rev-collector/index.js

finally can index.js--->index.js?v=098f6bcd;

but maintenance is difficult if the version is upgraded

Is there any other way?

other way I see that github:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev/issues/27

I use it in gulpfile.js and create hashes.json  ,that format is like that{"style.css":"style.css?v=11fdcc1970"}

how can i use gulp-rev-collect to modified html pages

Comment: Are you trying to something different than the gulp-rev-collect docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-collector ?  Because that is the example they provide: using gulp-rev and gulp-rev.manifest to ceate a json manifest and then gulp-rev-collector to modify the html.

Comment: yes, gulp-rev-collector can handle like that{"style-11fdcc1970.css":"style.cs"}  ,
 but like {"style.css":"style.css?v=11fdcc1970"} this style can't modified;